# Nono-Cube: Approach at Your Own Risk

Tags: word, visual, grid-deduction, three-dimensional, nonogram

> Inspired by [jafe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41973/jafe)'s 3D nonograms :)

Answer is one word.
[image]

<sub>This puzzle is a part of [Ooohh, it all makes sense now! :D](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85613/ooohh-it-all-makes-sense-now-d)</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nonogram solution:

> ```
> . . . . .
> . # # # .
> . # . . .
> . # . . .
> . . . . .
>
> . # . # .
> . . . . .
> . . . . #
> # . . . .
> . . # . .
>
> . # . # .
> # . . . .
> # . . . #
> # . . . .
> . # # # .
>
> . # # # .
> # . . . .
> # . . . #
> # . . . .
> . # . # .
>
> . . . . .
> . # . # .
> . # # # .
> . # # # .
> . . . . .
> ```

and with the Eye of Faith we can see that

> the six sides of the cube bear the letters of the word RADIUM.

Comment: gotcha, a check for you here!